# Magento Speed issue google PageSpeed Insights Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, cache, full-page-cache

I tried this methods [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91149/eliminate-render-blocking-js-and-css)
to speed site, but still not working. please suggest me how to speed up the site for mobile version.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed pagespeed mod for apache on my server.. Things are 90+ now. If you have root access, i would recommend doing that. Link:- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and i got 84/100 after optimize css delivery, but optimizing js delivery is not much easy as magento need to load some js at top of page.
pls read this article, u can get some help
http://www.sagaracommerce.com/blog/optiming-css-delivery-for-magento-as-per-google-page-speed-insight-tool/

Thanks
Prajosh